TChart Performance of whole form delphi FMX
My App with FMX on Windows has a standard TChart with a around 10 fastline series. Every series has a lot of data-points. After loading the data in the chart I will just set a TPanel(also on the form) from visible:=False to true.
The displaying of the panel takes about 4 seconds. The same when hiding the panel again.
To show this issue I have made a small test app, see attached. The testcase has these steps:

click fillchart - this takes some time, but this is not my issue
click showpanel and see how long it takes until the panel is shown. Same when click and pull the border of the form to enlarge the form. (Chart ist not aligned as client so the size does not change)

The app show the amount of chart repaint events in a label. This is done with a timer and in the event afterdraw of the chart the amount will be increased.
So if you playing with the app size, clicking the chart, moving over the legend, click in the memo and so on you see that there are a lot of repaint events.
You will also see some commented lines in the code what I have tried to fix this issue. (setting autorepaint to false)
I have made a call to embarcadero and the technician has checked it and the result ist that this should be a tchart issue.
So I will be happy for all ideas and help.
Thanks a lot.
Andreas
unit1.pas
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMXTee.Series, FMXTee.Engine, FMXTee.Procs,
  FMXTee.Chart, FMX.Memo.Types, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Chart1: TChart;
    Series1: TFastLineSeries;
    Series2: TFastLineSeries;
    Series3: TFastLineSeries;
    Series4: TFastLineSeries;
    Series5: TFastLineSeries;
    Series6: TFastLineSeries;
    Series9: TFastLineSeries;
    Series11: TFastLineSeries;
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button2: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Label1: TLabel;
    afterdrawCounterVal: TLabel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Chart1BeforeDrawChart(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    tickCountChartDraw:cardinal;
    afterdrawCounter:Cardinal;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses winapi.Windows;
{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  panel1.Visible:=not panel1.visible;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,j:Integer;
  tickCount:Cardinal;
begin
  tickCount:=GetTickCount;
  Randomize;
  chart1.BeginUpdate;
  for i := 0 to Chart1.SeriesCount-1 do begin
    Chart1.series[i].BeginUpdate;
    for j := 0 to 100000 do
      Chart1.series[i].AddXY(j,Random(100));
    Chart1.series[i].EndUpdate;
  end;
  chart1.EndUpdate;
  memo1.Lines.Add('filling Chart with data:'+(GetTickCount-tickCount).ToString);
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //memo1.Lines.Add('Chart After Draw '+(GetTickCount-tickCountChartDraw).ToString);
  Inc(afterdrawCounter);
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1BeforeDrawChart(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //memo1.Lines.Add('Chart Before Draw');
  //tickCountChartDraw:=getTickcount;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  panel1.Visible:=False;
  afterdrawCounter:=0;
//  chart1.AutoRepaint:=false;
//  Series1.AutoRepaint := False;
//  Series2.AutoRepaint := False;
//  Series3.AutoRepaint := False;
//  Series4.AutoRepaint := False;
//  Series5.AutoRepaint := False;
//  Series6.AutoRepaint := False;
//  Series9.AutoRepaint := False;
//  Series11.AutoRepaint := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  afterdrawCounterVal.Text:=afterdrawCounter.ToString;
end;

end.

unit1.fmx
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 620
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Chart1: TChart
    Position.X = 56.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
    Foot.Font.StyleExt = {00040000000200000004000000}
    Legend.Title.Font.StyleExt = {00070000000000000004000000}
    SubFoot.Font.StyleExt = {00040000000200000004000000}
    Title.Text.Strings = (
      'TChart')
    View3D = False
    Zoom.Brush.Kind = None
    Zoom.Pen.Fill.Color = claSilver
    OnAfterDraw = Chart1AfterDraw
    OnBeforeDrawChart = Chart1BeforeDrawChart
    TabOrder = 0
    Size.Width = 529.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 417.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    ColorPaletteIndex = 13
    object Series1: TFastLineSeries
      HoverElement = []
      LinePen.Color = xFF4466A3
      LinePen.Fill.Color = xFF4466A3
      XValues.Name = 'X'
      XValues.Order = loAscending
      YValues.Name = 'Y'
      YValues.Order = loNone
    end
    object Series2: TFastLineSeries
      HoverElement = []
      LinePen.Color = xFFF39C35
      LinePen.Fill.Color = xFFF39C35
      XValues.Name = 'X'
      XValues.Order = loAscending
      YValues.Name = 'Y'
      YValues.Order = loNone
    end
    object Series3: TFastLineSeries
      HoverElement = []
      LinePen.Color = xFFF14C14
      LinePen.Fill.Color = xFFF14C14
      XValues.Name = 'X'
      XValues.Order = loAscending
      YValues.Name = 'Y'
      YValues.Order = loNone
    end
    object Series4: TFastLineSeries
      HoverElement = []
      LinePen.Color = xFF4E97A8
      LinePen.Fill.Color = xFF4E97A8
      XValues.Name = 'X'
      XValues.Order = loAscending
      YValues.Name = 'Y'
      YValues.Order = loNone
    end
    object Series5: TFastLineSeries
      HoverElement = []
      LinePen.Color = xFF2B406B
      LinePen.Fill.Color = xFF2B406B
      XValues.Name = 'X'
      XValues.Order = loAscending
      YValues.Name = 'Y'
      YValues.Order = loNone
    end
    object Series6: TFastLineSeries
      HoverElement = []
      LinePen.Color = xFF1D7B63
      LinePen.Fill.Color = xFF1D7B63
      XValues.Name = 'X'
      XValues.Order = loAscending
      YValues.Name = 'Y'
      YValues.Order = loNone
    end
    object Series9: TFastLineSeries
      HoverElement = []
      LinePen.Color = xFF5DB79E
      LinePen.Fill.Color = xFF5DB79E
      XValues.Name = 'X'
      XValues.Order = loAscending
      YValues.Name = 'Y'
      YValues.Order = loNone
    end
    object Series11: TFastLineSeries
      HoverElement = []
      LinePen.Color = xFFF3EA8D
      LinePen.Fill.Color = xFFF3EA8D
      XValues.Name = 'X'
      XValues.Order = loAscending
      YValues.Name = 'Y'
      YValues.Order = loNone
    end
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 136.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 10.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'showpanel'
    TextSettings.Trimming = None
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Position.X = 328.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 2
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Position.X = 24.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 10.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 3
    Text = 'fillchart'
    TextSettings.Trimming = None
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [Pan, LongTap, DoubleTap]
    DataDetectorTypes = []
    Align = Bottom
    Position.Y = 512.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 108.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 4
    Viewport.Width = 636.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 104.000000000000000000
  end
  object Label1: TLabel
    Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 487.000000000000000000
    Text = 'AfterdrawCounter'
    TabOrder = 6
  end
  object afterdrawCounterVal: TLabel
    Position.X = 136.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 487.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 7
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 512
    Top = 480
  end
end


project1.dpr
program Project1;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.


It seems to me that you have totally missed the point, that TChart is a visual component to display data values as a chart. Its purpose is not to host massive amounts of data, that doesn't even fit on a screen. For data amounts of 100k data points you need to write code that lifts reasonable sized intervals (say, a few hundreds points at a time) of data from the mass to the chart to be displayed.

In my real app I have data like from a oscilloscope. These are temperaturelogs over one day. The user needs to see the different curves for the whole day to see abnormal issues in combination of more than 2 curves. After that perhaps he dive in with zoom. So I don't know how I should decrease the data without loosing information for the user. For me it is clear that the loading needs some time and also the zoom or shift. But when I only set a panel to visible there is no reason why the chart has to be redrawn. If there is a posibility to prevent the automatic redraw this would be great.

Are you really loosing data if it can't be displayed?  Maybe not the average but the maximum or minimum per visible data point is what you should be graphing?  A candlestick type graph which shows both could be useful.  The lowest point is the minimum for the period, the highest point is the maximum, and then include a line between them that shows the average.

You still did not indicate the actual max number of measures, so I will not spend more time on this. But as a hint I can say that e.g. showing/moving/closing an overlapping form doesn't trigger a repaint of the chart.

Thanks for info, my real data consists of about 20 temperature and pressure series as fastlines. All have a value max every 500ms. Can be less if there are no changes. The chart show one day. This lead max to: 2 values per sec -> 26060*24=172800 values per series. The usecase here is: user has to analyse measured data. If you use my example you will see that the event onafterdraw is also fired when only show or hide the panel. The event inc the afterdrawCounter and the timer print this value. After clicking the button to hide or show the panel the amount has increased. Thats the problem

As I already told you in my first comment: "Its purpose is not to host massive amounts of data, that doesn't even fit on a screen." Visually, the user can only evaluate a part of that data anyway. Ergo, store the mass of data in memory and call up to display shorter timespans (that fit on the display). Write code that analyzes the data and informs about deviations from expectations, so the user knows where to look for details. Once you reduce the number of simultaneous data points in the chart you have no problems with overlapping panels or whatever.

If you do not care about the time it takes to perform the initial generation of the chart and do not care about any events on the chart, you can paint to an offscreen canvas (http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/tutorials/UserGuide/html/manu390n.htm#internal_bitmap) and then display a copy of that bitmap.

One reason that performance is lagging is the number of elements in your X axis. Is there some way you could reduce this to something more meaningful?  Maybe the average over a period and then provide a "zoom" feature to dig deeper into an individual data point?
I agree it is likely a problem with the lack of optimization in the TChart component as it is likely iterating over all data points to draw the chart and I doubt that your form is at least 100000 pixels wide. If your usable graph is only 2000 pixels wide, then you can take the average of every 50 items and reduce the graph to only 2000 data points which would improve performance.
